# Is it a good idea to use wait() / notify() for a large amount of requests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, concurrency, wait

I'm fairly new to Spring Boot and hence don't know yet in what exact way threads are managed there.

My question is: in a REST Spring Boot server application, is it save to let certain requests `wait()` for data to be modified, or is the number of concurrent requests limited, which would mean that blocking would result in availability issues?

Comment: "*... is the number of concurrent requests limited... ?*" - Requests are proocessed by threads. Threads are always a limited resource. --- In general, we do not need to use `wait()` / `notify[All]()`. Is there a specific use case you have in mind?

Comment: yes, I'm working on a game whose state gets modified every now and then and instead of letting the client poll every x milliseconds, spamming the server with GET requests, I'd like to notify clients only when their objects of interest have actually changed. I heard about Websockets, which would certainly solve this problem, but I'm still hoping I don't have to learn another framework :D

Comment: HTTP communication, in general, is initiated by the client. The server does not "push" information to the client. If we want to send information from the server to the client "when they happen", then websockets and/or Server Sent Events is the way to go.

Comment: the client is a frontend @MatheusCirillo

Comment: @MatheusCirillo no, it is not suited. Given enough clients, this will brick the server (similar to a [slow loris attack (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security))). Furthermore, we would only be able to send a single information package as response, not a continuous stream of information "as they occur". The client would have to request the "next" information through another request.

Comment: that was my plan, subscribing for the next update every time @Turing85 
unfortunately I'm bound to HTTP. Websockets and Server Sent Events can be implemented in HTTP, can they?

Comment: [Server Sent Events (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) are part of the HTTP standard, [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) are a sepaprate protocol, but compatible with HTTP. Again, blocking the response until "something happens" is a terrible idea; it is awfully inefficient resource-wise and given enough requests, this will lead to problems.

Comment: thank you very much @Turing85 I hoped to hear something else but it was the answer I needed :D

Comment: @Turing85 wow, sorry...I forgot to put 'are NOT suited'...comment deleted, thank you..